# In Rspec Capybara integration test ,Controllers not maintaining session after login/signup, getting current_user nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

I have a test case where after registration devise `signup(resource_name, resource)` method is called and a `redirect_url` is sent back to front end , which in turns load the requested page by `window.location = redirect_url`, though when the next page is hit the next page controller is getting current_user as nil.

Test Case

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature "sign up with investment profile", js: true do

  context 'all fields are valid' do
    let(:goal) do
      create(
        :goal,
        risk_level: Tags::BALANCED,
        age: 30
      )
    end

    before 'valid sign up steps' do
      create(:currency_conversion)
      f = File.read("#{Dir.pwd}/spec/response/marketplace/performance.json")
      allow(Marketplace::StrategyService).to receive(:get_performance_trail).and_return(JSON.parse(f))
      model_portfolio_version = create(:model_portfolio_version, :with_performance_trails)
      goal.model_portfolio_version = model_portfolio_version
      goal.save!
      goal.reload
      visit_page_containing_ajax "/suggestions/#{goal.url_hash}"
      click_link 'Next: Personal Details'
      within('.signup-page-header') do
        expect(page).to have_content 'SIGN UP'
      end

      fill_registration_fields(signup_email)

      fill_personal_info_form
      wait_for_ajax

      find('.btn-primary').click
      wait_for_ajax

      fill_identification_form
      wait_for_ajax

      find('.btn-primary').click
      wait_for_ajax

      fill_declaration_form
      wait_for_ajax

      find('.btn-primary').click
      wait_for_ajax

      expect(page).to have_current_path(kyc_dashboard_path(goal.url_hash))
    end

    context 'User should get registered and redirected to kyc dashboard' do
      let(:signup_email) { 'email@example.com' }

      context 'user' do
        it 'creates investor account' do
          expect(page).to have_content('Your registration is successful')
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

PS: This is happening in test environment only

After debugging for hours , I found that we are maintaining session in `active_record_store` when i change it to `cookie_store` spec works fine.

Comment: Show your test code - and then check the urls that are being redirected to are all the same domain as the login/signup (otherwise the session cookies won't be valid)

Comment: @ThomasWalpole updated code, redirect url is a subdomain. This works fine in dev environment , I am getting session there. This case is only in test environment.

Comment: We need the test code (the test case code)

Comment: @ThomasWalpole my bad forgot to attach test case, updated now, thanks

Comment: and what is the exact error message you're getting (and at which line of that test) - As a side note, 99.9% of the time you really shouldn't need `wait_for_ajax` if your tests are written properly.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole thanks for your time , It is happening because we are maintaining session in `active_record_store` , when I change it to `cookie_store` session persist,